# How to shorten time processing to read thousand line of files - bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have thousand of lines in a file and need to read lines by lines until pattern matched. Example:

```
1
2
3
pattern 1
pattern 2
pattern 1
pattern 2
....thousand lines here
pattern 3 - pass or fail
...thousand line
...repeat pattern 1, 2, 3
```

Pattern 1 and 2 will be store in array if pattern 3 value is pass, if fail, the value will be ignored. Pattern 3 will always appears after pattern 1 and 2.  Below is my code written in bash script:

```
while read -r line
    do


        if [[ $line= 'Pattern 1' ]]; then
            ID1=$line
        else if [[ $line='Pattern 2']]; then 
            ID2=$line
        else if [[$line='Pattern 3']]; then
            VALUE=`echo $line | cut -d '|' -f 4`
            if [[ $VALUE='Pass' ]];then
            Pattern1+=($ID1)
            Pattern2+=($ID2)
            fi
         else
       echo "do nothing"
       fi


        fi              
    done <<< file.txt
```

However, this method takes time to process thousands line of the file and seems not working well. How to shorten the time processing and the code can work well?

Comment: Why do you care about time? If you want to code a fast program, `bash` is not the right tool. Coding the *same* thing in [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk), or [Python](http://python.org/), or [Go](http://golang.org/), or [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) or C or C++ ... would probably make it faster. Your current `bash` script forks several processes for each line with `Pattern 3`

Comment: So you probably need to learn and use some other programming language.

Comment: Just use `awk` and it'll be done in under a second.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, starting a new process is somehow expansive: at least a few milliseconds, and perhaps much more

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I need to use bash script because i nedd to add this function to current script. May i know if using awk, how to do it?

Comment: To speed up processing you could pre-filter the input file `$ egrep 'pat1|pat2|pat3' datafile | bash yourscript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It seems your fields are separated by pipe symbols (`|`), so you can tell `awk` that with:

```
awk -F'|'  '...script...'
```

It seems that your pass/fail signal is a `P` or an `F` in the second to last field, so you can test for `Pass` like this:

```
awk -F'|'  '$(NF-1)=="P" /print/' file
```

So I guess you want something like:

```
awk -F'|' '
     /Pattern1/             {id1=$0}
     /Pattern2/             {id2=$0}
     /^QA/ && $(NF-1)=="P"  {print id1; print id2}' file.txt
```

**Original Answer**

Untested because I'm only on an iPhone, but just to get you started:

```
awk '/Pattern1/           {id1=$0}
     /Pattern2/           {id2=$0}
     /Pattern3/ && /pass/ {print id1; print id2}' file.txt
```

Maybe put those in a single array and split the array on every second element with a simple `bash` for loop.

You can get that in an array in a `bash` script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo I am a bash script
#
# Fill bash array using awk
arr=( $(awk ... file.txt) )
```

Comment: i tried but the code still included pattern 3 - fail. the pattern3 actually soomething like this-  QA:123|23|23|F|12 for fail, QA:123|23|23|P|12 means pass. the pattern3 is QA.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean when you put unformatted code into comments. Please click `edit` under your question and paste in an accurate representation of what you start with and an accurate representation of what you end up with. Then add a comment here so I know you have updated it.